# Is one cup of coffee a day good?

Tags: health, caffeine

Is there any effect of drinking coffee daily?
Is coffee harmful for health?How can I make my coffee healthier? Are there any benefits of drinking coffee daily?

Answer (score 0):

In [Mayoclinics](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/caffeine/art-20045678) article, they say that healthy adults can have up to 4 cups of coffee a day. However, if you're experiencing side effects - such as: a migraine headache, insomnia, nervousness, irritability, restlessness, frequent urination or inability to control urination, stomach upset, fast heartbeat, muscle tremors) - to consider cutting back the amount of coffee you intake. This is true not just for those that have more than 4 cups of coffee a day, but for all who drink coffee. Some people are more susceptible to coffee's effects than others, so if you feel woozy or unsteady even after two, maybe it's a good idea to cut back. If coffee is affecting your sleep schedule, also cut back. If you use it to wake up in the morning or rely on it, perhaps going to bed sooner is a better option as sleep deprivation is one of the largest catalysts in becoming an unhealthy adult. This is not to say you should change yourself overnight, but change gradually if you decide to do so.

This said, here are some [health benefits of coffee.](https://www.homegrounds.co/15-research-backed-health-benefits-of-coffee/)

With this my own experience: I personally find myself drinking 4 cups of coffee a day. While they're not all standard cups, if I break it down I drink up to 32oz of coffee a day. I find that if I ever have coffee past 15:00 I have insomnia that night and I'm just too jittery to fall asleep.